# Searching for words in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app currently lists words that have been parsed into a database (SQLite). I want to add a search box to my rails application that looks through my dictionary of words and returns the word they searched for in the table format that is currently presented in my view:

```
<% @words.each do |word| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= word.word %></td>
    <td><%= word.wordtype %></td>
    <td><%= word.description %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', word %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I am new to rails and ruby so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a simple search (that doesn't allow misspellings but allows partial spellings) you could make your action something like this (rename the method name to whatever you want/need it to be):

```
def search
  # Replace Word model with whatever the model is actually called
  @words = Word.where('word LIKE "%?%"', params[:query])
end
```

Note that this action should be used with the GET method. Subsequently, we don't need to use StrongParameters.